# Meaning of the word touting

Tags: meaning

According to dictionary.com the basic meaning of the word touting is to describe or advertise boastfully; publicize or promote; praise extravagantly
But why would locales tout limestone water supplies? Can I replace it with more accurate synonym?

[Meanwhile, some of the best bourbon made outside of Kentucky hails from locales touting limestone water supplies.](http://www.eater.com/drinks/2015/11/25/9784954/spirits-water-purity-water-sources)

Comment: Presumably those locales brag about their water coming out of limestone. A guess is that this means that the water has certain minerals deemed beneficial for health or taste.

Comment: I guess you are right, thanx

Comment: I think it's effectively a misuse of the verb *to tout*, for which the relevant OED definition is *To importune (a person) in a touting manner;  (b) to solicit custom for (a thing), to try to sell; also (U.S.) in extended sense, to recommend.* I would say it's fine to refer to ***locals** touting their water* (*locals* being the people who live in the area), but I don't think *locales = locations* works at all well as the verb subject.